# jquery is not working with adding content dynamically by ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i am **dynamically** adding content using ajax after added the content i am trying to change background image using jquery it's not working this is my code.

Ajax code:

```
 function loadlogin(url, loginFunction)
 {
   var xhttp;
   xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
       {
         loginFunction(this);
       }
    };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
```

And this is my jquery code :

```
<div class="img-fluid" src="img.png">
<script>
  $(document).on( "click", ".img-fluid", function(event) {
    var background = $(this).attr("src");
   $(".fullpage_wrapper").css("background","url(" + background + ")");
 });
</script>
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello ,welcome to stack-overflow. do you get any error on console?

Comment: no i am not getting any error on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ajaxComplete` func, so Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete event.

For Example :

```
<div class="log"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      $(".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
     //your code here
    });
</script>
```

without ajaxcomplete (using `background-image` instead `background`):

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var background=$(".img-fluid").attr("data-src");
        $(".fullpage_wrapper").css("background-image","url("+background+")");
       
        });
```

```css
.fullpage_wrapper
{
width:300px;
display:block;
height:60px;
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="fullpage_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img-fluid" data-src="https://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png">
```

**Update :**
instead of `.css()` you can use:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage = "url('background')";
```

then add id (i used `test`) name to your class.

Comment: i tried your solution but it didn't work for me actually i want to change image on the click of button that on() is working in my code but css() is not working here.

Comment: @DhruvRaj i updated my code. if your script doesn't run after Ajax complete maybe Ajax call has a issue. also its better use `background-image` instead `background`

Comment: i getting this error in console.  Cannot read property 'style' of null  can you tell me how can i solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried my solution? as you can see it's working here

Comment: i tried your solution everything is working but only css() is not working i don't know why.

Comment: i tried your updated code from that one i am getting this error in console:-  Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: i got what is issue, somehow your div class doesn't get loaded in the HTML maybe it has syntax issue. it is the reason both approaches don't work

Comment: please check again my code i had forgot to add `;` to the end of one declaration.

Comment: var background=$(".img-fluid").attr("data-src");

Comment: i wish i could help more , please try inspect element to see is your div class fully loaded or not.and have you tried ajaxcomplete event?

Comment: @DhruvRaj it was my pleasure bro.if my answer really helped you i will grateful up vote or set it as correct :)

Comment: thanks for your help bro my problem has been solved. i did really silly mistake.